# Read .xlsx file and store it into list

Tags: excel, csv, flutter, dart, xlsx

I want to read a xlsx file (or csv would work as well), and then save the column-values into three different lists. I have achieve this in both iOS and Android but I haven't found any great solution for this in flutter/dart.

Any idea on how I could achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: There's a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) to parse CSV data.